# Simple polynomial representing a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having difficulty wrapping both lobes around this simple linear algebra problem. The problem states that for the following subset of $F^{3}$, determine whether it is a subspace:

{(${x_1}$, ${x_2}$, ${x_3}$)$\in$ $F^{3}$ : ${x_1}$ + 2${x_2}$ + 3${x_3}$ = 4}

The solution is: Let U={(${x_1}$, ${x_2}$, ${x_3}$ $\in$ $F^{3}$ : ${x_1}$ + 2${x_2}$ + 3${x_3}$ = 4}. Then (4,0,0)$\in$ U but 0(4,0,0), which equals (0,0,0), is not in U. Thus U is not closed under scalar multiplication. Thus U is not a subspace of $F^{3}$. 
I don't understand why (0,0,0) is not in U. It seems to me that the polynomial could be re-written as ${x_1}$ + 2${x_2}$ + 3${x_3}$ - 4 = 0, and if all the coefficients are zero, then everything on the left side of the equation would be equal to zero, so it would be a subspace. What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

When you put in $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ you get $0=4$ which is clearly not possible. Thus $(0,0,0)\not\in U$. But any subspce needs to contain $0$

Comment: Why can't I subtract 4 from both sides, making it 0=0?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

In vector notation, the elements of your set $U$ have the form:
$$
u=\begin{bmatrix}
4-2x_2-3x_3\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $[0,0,0]^T$ has not this form.